Displaying text side-by-side with pie chart
I'm using pgf-pie and trying to create text beside a pie chart. My code looks like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}  

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth} p{0.45\textwidth}}

\raggedleft \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[radius=2, color={black!10, black!20, black!30, black!40}]{33/Y, 26/N, 22/A, 19/V}
\end{tikzpicture} &

\raggedright The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

which renders

How do I make the text go up so that it is aligned? Thanks.

Welcome to TeX.SE please provide full code as MWE, i.e., from \documentclass to \end{document}

@MadyYuvi Thanks. I've edited the question.

Use m type column in array package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}  
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabular}{m{0.45\textwidth} m{0.45\textwidth}}

\raggedleft \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[radius=2, color={black!10, black!20, black!30, black!40}]{33/Y, 26/N, 22/A, 19/V}
\end{tikzpicture} &

\raggedright The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

However, why just put a node in the tikzpicture without tabular?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}  
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[radius=2, color={black!10, black!20, black!30, black!40}]{33/Y, 26/N, 22/A, 19/V}
    \node [xshift=2.5cm,anchor=west,text width=0.45\textwidth] {The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}



Another simple way is move picture baseline to vertical cener by use of its option baseline:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth} p{0.45\textwidth}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]% <---
    \pie[radius=2, color={black!10, black!20, black!30, black!40}]{33/Y, 26/N, 22/A, 19/V}
\end{tikzpicture} 
    &   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


Edit:
As @Tom noted in his comment, above solution works if text in the second column is has only few lines. If it longer, than is obvious that you need to change p column type to m type of array` package to get more general solution:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth} m{0.45\textwidth}} % <---
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]% <---
    \pie[radius=2, color={black!10, black!20, black!30, black!40}]{33/Y, 26/N, 22/A, 19/V}
\end{tikzpicture} 
    &   \lipsum[1]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

gives:

This is more general solution.

The tabular environment becomes optional.

This will be not working if the text was a long paragraph.

@Tom, you are right. In such a cases te second column should be of m type defined by array package. I will add this option asap.

oops... baseline option is the one I've searched, but bad luck, couldn't able to find out, you are great

I've splitted your code into two tabular mode, and used the additional package adjustbox.sty, and the modified MWE is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}  
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent 
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.45\textwidth}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[radius=2, color={black!10, black!20, black!30, black!40}]{33/Y, 26/N, 22/A, 19/V}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}\quad
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.45\textwidth}}
 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}


EDIT
Modified the MWE as suggested by Zarko in his comment:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}  
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=m}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[radius=2, color={black!10, black!20, black!30, black!40}]{33/Y,
26/N, 22/A, 19/V}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}\hfil%
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=m}
\parbox{0.45\linewidth}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.} 
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}

\end{document}



Interesting answer. according to OP request you should change valign option t  to m. Also you can drop the tqbular environment in the first box.

@Zarko Done, as you suggested and thanks a lot, to improve the suggestion in a better way

@MadyYuvi Always all the best things.

@Sebastiano Much thanks for your kind words, Happy ThanksGivings to you and your family too :-D
